# JSP and Java Servlet not passing parameter to JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I didn't have trouble with this before, and I actually have a working implementation with a different class. But for some reason, this example fails.

I have a class called `InfoServlet.java`:

```
@WebServlet("/info_servlet")
public class InfoServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      request.setAttribute("test", "hello world.");
      request.getRequestDispatcher("info_servlet.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

And my jsp page `info_servlet.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    <p><c:out value="${test}" /></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I go to `localhost:8080/MySite/info_servlet.jsp` my output is only

## HELLO

For reference, I'm using tomcat 7 and servlet 3.0 in java. I didn't have trouble passing in an object so I'm unsure why all the sudden it won't let me display the value in `info_servlet.jsp`

Answer (score 2):

Everything works as expected. You are setting the "test" attribute within the servlet: if you go directly to the .jsp, bypassing the servlet, the attribute simply won't be set. Its value therefore will be `null` and the expression language will silently ignore it.